# Specifically use make instead of ninja when importing cmake project in KDevelop

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop

I am trying to set up a c++ project I am working on in KDevelop, since it looked like an interesting IDE. For this project I am using cmake and make, but for some reason when I import the project using the CMakeLists.txt file it is setting up the KDevelop project to use ninja. I haven't been able to find any way to switch the project to using make, either online or just by digging through the menus. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant setting is `Settings -> Configure KDevelop -> CMake -> Default generator`.

If the build directory is already configured with `-G"Unix Makefiles"` (or another generator) when you import the project, KDevelop should detect and use that backend regardless of the default.